# How to make a nice 3D plot in R for time series spectral data

Tags: r, date, graph, 3d, time-series

I am trying to do a nice 3D plot using time series UV-Vis spectral data, like the first 3D graph below.

[image: Example 3D graph]

I used dput() function to show my data as below.

```
dput(head(Data))
```

and get:

```
structure(list(Wavelength = c(250, 252.5, 255, 257.5, 260, 262.5
), Date = structure(c(1365465600, 1365552000, 1365638400, 1365724800, 
1365811200, 1365897600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    X250 = c(25.736217791411, 25.1182597222222, 24.8889567642957, 
    24.4881150070126, 24.2313916666667, 24.0346564673157), X252.5 = c(25.2168558282209, 
    24.6022625, 24.375429567643, 23.979541374474, 23.7248569444444, 
    23.5341668984701), X255 = c(24.6049539877301, 23.9896638888889, 
    23.7649888423989, 23.3753758765778, 23.1248263888889, 22.9342726008345
    ), X257.5 = c(24.0257944785276, 23.4037875, 23.1804435146443, 
    22.795541374474, 22.5493486111111, 22.35478581363), X260 = c(23.5917024539877, 
    22.9615486111111, 22.7389818688982, 22.3544109396914, 22.1091222222222, 
    21.9127635605007), X262.5 = c(23.1529110429448, 22.5264, 
    22.3051380753138, 21.924920056101, 21.6777583333333, 21.4858831710709
    ), X265 = c(22.5382085889571, 21.918125, 21.6982092050209, 
    21.3252145862553, 21.0800125, 20.8941794158554), X267.5 = c(21.8748957055215, 
    21.2488722222222, 21.0308619246862, 20.6643941093969, 20.4225541666667, 
    20.2340041724617), X270 = c(21.2791380368098, 20.6435263888889, 
    20.4248619246862, 20.0633674614306, 19.823075, 19.6308664812239
    ), X272.5 = c(20.7223159509202, 20.0815388888889, 19.8637377963738, 
    19.5049382889201, 19.2644375, 19.0733532684284), X275 = c(20.1307699386503, 
    19.4878583333333, 19.2719930264993, 18.9178920056101, 18.6778583333333, 
    18.487123783032), X277.5 = c(19.4758159509202, 18.8334013888889, 
    18.6168423988842, 18.2683702664797, 18.0308791666667, 17.8428414464534
    ), X280 = c(18.8002392638037, 18.1555375, 17.9391743375174, 
    17.5960126227209, 17.3601361111111, 17.1767204450626), X282.5 = c(18.1441809815951, 
    17.4953208333333, 17.2798758716876, 16.9426002805049, 16.7091777777778, 
    16.5276926286509), X285 = c(17.5349570552147, 16.8845097222222, 
    16.6697126917713, 16.337541374474, 16.1053763888889, 15.9246383866481
    ), X287.5 = c(16.8937300613497, 16.2423861111111, 16.0298493723849, 
    15.7046171107994, 15.4740472222222, 15.2938845618915), X290 = c(16.2328404907975, 
    15.582175, 15.3718940027894, 15.0537826086957, 14.8253291666667, 
    14.646668984701), X292.5 = c(15.5751472392638, 14.9258291666667, 
    14.7170446304045, 14.4051360448808, 14.1804194444444, 14.0051933240612
    ), X295 = c(14.9421717791411, 14.2904180555556, 14.0835034867504, 
    13.778301542777, 13.5566902777778, 13.3817329624478), X297.5 = c(14.4052392638037, 
    13.7537152777778, 13.5474421199442, 13.2471725105189, 13.0260375, 
    12.8530055632823), X300 = c(13.9050889570552, 13.2578347222222, 
    13.0537364016736, 12.7592973352034, 12.5405888888889, 12.3732670375522
    ), X302.5 = c(13.401036809816, 12.7586194444445, 12.5570264993026, 
    12.2684992987377, 12.0533902777778, 11.8884353268428), X305 = c(12.902717791411, 
    12.2623319444444, 12.0613933054393, 11.7787826086956, 11.5651972222222, 
    11.4043337969402), X307.5 = c(12.4249355828221, 11.7857791666667, 
    11.5858940027894, 11.3107840112202, 11.0999777777778, 10.9374005563282
    ), X310 = c(11.9935245398773, 11.3549347222222, 11.1571324965133, 
    10.8868260869565, 10.67955, 10.5179193324061), X312.5 = c(11.6203098159509, 
    10.9819680555556, 10.7849539748954, 10.516744740533, 10.3119236111111, 
    10.156892906815), X315 = c(11.2705674846626, 10.63485, 10.4406555090656, 
    10.177301542777, 9.97497638888889, 9.82023783031989), X317.5 = c(10.9098711656442, 
    10.2797055555556, 10.0875216178522, 9.82828471248247, 9.62720138888889, 
    9.47325173852573), X320 = c(10.5516625766871, 9.922075, 9.73211157601116, 
    9.47973772791024, 9.28055, 9.12974826147427), X322.5 = c(10.2039049079755, 
    9.57341805555556, 9.38568758716876, 9.13822159887798, 8.94393888888889, 
    8.79378581363004), X325 = c(9.86461042944785, 9.23893472222222, 
    9.05190516039052, 8.80583450210379, 8.61297777777778, 8.46346731571627
    ), X327.5 = c(9.5730490797546, 8.95366388888889, 8.76786750348675, 
    8.52597615708275, 8.33285972222222, 8.18865924895688), X330 = c(9.29567791411043, 
    8.67920416666667, 8.49494421199442, 8.25632117812062, 8.06634305555556, 
    7.92368984700974), X332.5 = c(9.0010981595092, 8.38594305555556, 
    8.20200139470014, 7.96879803646564, 7.78189166666667, 7.63967593880389
    ), X335 = c(8.71511349693252, 8.09972916666667, 7.92145885634589, 
    7.69297335203366, 7.50750694444444, 7.3643421418637), X337.5 = c(8.45265644171779, 
    7.84026666666667, 7.66316178521618, 7.43814305750351, 7.25333333333333, 
    7.11477607788595), X340 = c(8.19838036809816, 7.59187361111111, 
    7.41271827057183, 7.19209256661992, 7.00985416666667, 6.87590959666203
    ), X342.5 = c(7.95462883435583, 7.34913194444444, 7.17332914923291, 
    6.95607433380084, 6.77643055555556, 6.64161752433936), X345 = c(7.72929754601227, 
    7.12695138888889, 6.95060669456067, 6.7338920056101, 6.55681388888889, 
    6.42844089012517), X347.5 = c(7.50222699386503, 6.90189583333333, 
    6.72852022315202, 6.51498036465638, 6.33897916666667, 6.21110848400556
    ), X350 = c(7.2898527607362, 6.69248472222222, 6.52281171548117, 
    6.3138920056101, 6.13989722222222, 6.00979554937413), X352.5 = c(7.07927300613497, 
    6.48439166666667, 6.31443514644351, 6.10986956521739, 5.93754583333333, 
    5.81149652294854), X355 = c(6.86355214723926, 6.26889861111111, 
    6.09972524407252, 5.89783450210379, 5.72706527777778, 5.60363838664812
    ), X357.5 = c(6.6658527607362, 6.07161111111111, 5.90622873082287, 
    5.70649649368864, 5.53700833333333, 5.41251877607789), X360 = c(6.47400613496932, 
    5.88162777777778, 5.71633472803347, 5.5187713884993, 5.35024444444444, 
    5.22833796940195), X362.5 = c(6.30347852760736, 5.71433888888889, 
    5.54859414225942, 5.3527587657784, 5.1863375, 5.06425173852573
    ), X365 = c(6.16322699386503, 5.57911527777778, 5.41753835425384, 
    5.22367601683029, 5.05854027777778, 4.94001390820584), X367.5 = c(6.02653067484663, 
    5.44968333333333, 5.29124267782427, 5.10030294530154, 4.93744305555556, 
    4.82315020862309), X370 = c(5.86248466257669, 5.28735277777778, 
    5.12692747559275, 4.93981065918654, 4.77878055555556, 4.6638066759388
    ), X372.5 = c(5.68123006134969, 5.10715, 4.94811854951185, 
    4.764904628331, 4.60323333333333, 4.48933379694019), X375 = c(5.53815644171779, 
    4.96720416666667, 4.81097350069735, 4.62871388499299, 4.46926944444445, 
    4.35810987482615), X377.5 = c(5.40510429447853, 4.8370625, 
    4.68262761506276, 4.50320617110799, 4.34814444444444, 4.23741724617524
    ), X380 = c(5.30138343558282, 4.73901805555556, 4.5846889818689, 
    4.40751612903226, 4.25314444444444, 4.14589847009736), X382.5 = c(5.20306134969325, 
    4.64154722222222, 4.49053417015342, 4.31611079943899, 4.16125138888889, 
    4.05445757997218), X385 = c(5.07416871165644, 4.515375, 4.3646959553696, 
    4.19456802244039, 4.04227222222222, 3.93332127955494), X387.5 = c(4.96219325153374, 
    4.40868194444444, 4.25931520223152, 4.0922889200561, 3.9414, 
    3.83277607788595), X390 = c(4.83940797546012, 4.29276527777778, 
    4.14653974895398, 3.97920196353436, 3.82955277777778, 3.72600834492351
    ), X392.5 = c(4.71031288343558, 4.16622083333333, 4.02140446304045, 
    3.85572510518934, 3.70953194444445, 3.60538386648122), X395 = c(4.62059202453988, 
    4.07360138888889, 3.92935564853556, 3.76849228611501, 3.62277638888889, 
    3.51784283727399), X397.5 = c(4.49155521472393, 3.95385972222222, 
    3.81216178521618, 3.65344039270687, 3.50810833333333, 3.4116926286509
    ), X400 = c(4.37370858895706, 3.84129861111111, 3.70030125523013, 
    3.5432286115007, 3.39975277777778, 3.30254659248957), X402.5 = c(4.27044171779141, 
    3.738875, 3.59841562064156, 3.4434095371669, 3.30132638888889, 
    3.20369819193324), X405 = c(4.15562883435583, 3.6327375, 
    3.49318270571827, 3.33822159887798, 3.19675555555555, 3.10537273991655
    ), X407.5 = c(4.09877607361963, 3.57864305555556, 3.44027057182706, 
    3.28816129032258, 3.14875138888889, 3.05293602225313), X410 = c(4.01044785276074, 
    3.48679444444444, 3.35288842398884, 3.20463534361851, 3.06820833333333, 
    2.9671752433936), X412.5 = c(3.87490797546012, 3.35905694444444, 
    3.2244839609484, 3.07484291725105, 2.93775416666667, 2.8437983310153
    ), X415 = c(3.79108282208589, 3.28507361111111, 3.14952161785216, 
    3.00085273492286, 2.86421805555555, 2.77412378303199), X417.5 = c(3.68693558282209, 
    3.17824583333333, 3.04701394700139, 2.9043366058906, 2.76995972222222, 
    2.67318358831711), X420 = c(3.56437116564417, 3.05670972222222, 
    2.92747419804742, 2.786095371669, 2.65226666666667, 2.55702225312935
    ), X422.5 = c(3.51319018404908, 3.00990694444444, 2.87744769874477, 
    2.73367180925666, 2.60142361111111, 2.51227399165508), X425 = c(3.43132208588957, 
    2.92941805555555, 2.80041562064156, 2.65933099579243, 2.52816388888889, 
    2.43237969401947), X427.5 = c(3.31023926380368, 2.81629166666667, 
    2.68912831241283, 2.54957363253857, 2.41817777777778, 2.33177051460362
    ), X430 = c(3.26191717791411, 2.77505833333333, 2.64634030683403, 
    2.50681767180926, 2.37668055555556, 2.29549374130737), X432.5 = c(3.22984662576687, 
    2.74605555555556, 2.61894979079498, 2.48168022440393, 2.35282083333333, 
    2.26610987482615), X435 = c(3.13996932515337, 2.65807916666667, 
    2.5333179916318, 2.39782187938289, 2.26921388888889, 2.18432684283727
    ), X437.5 = c(3.08235582822086, 2.60515833333333, 2.4803249651325, 
    2.34626928471248, 2.21812083333333, 2.13608901251739), X440 = c(3.01686809815951, 
    2.54044583333333, 2.41671548117155, 2.2833842917251, 2.16062083333333, 
    2.07232267037552), X442.5 = c(2.93285889570552, 2.46135694444444, 
    2.33697489539749, 2.20531837307153, 2.08016805555556, 1.99902225312935
    ), X445 = c(2.8908773006135, 2.42607361111111, 2.30482426778243, 
    2.17530014025245, 2.04767916666667, 1.97140194714882), X447.5 = c(2.85198466257669, 
    2.38861111111111, 2.2694839609484, 2.14013884992987, 2.01676111111111, 
    1.93308901251738), X450 = c(2.8046472392638, 2.34394583333333, 
    2.22286750348675, 2.09689481065919, 1.97544444444445, 1.89651043115438
    ), X452.5 = c(2.77545705521472, 2.31733333333333, 2.20150627615063, 
    2.07733800841515, 1.95440277777778, 1.87571627260083), X455 = c(2.71198159509203, 
    2.26175277777778, 2.14609483960948, 2.02168022440393, 1.90238194444444, 
    1.82506536856745), X457.5 = c(2.69071779141104, 2.24759861111111, 
    2.1283709902371, 2.0067461430575, 1.88878055555556, 1.81217802503477
    ), X460 = c(2.63857055214724, 2.19480416666667, 2.07814365411437, 
    1.95862833099579, 1.84296111111111, 1.76875243393602), X462.5 = c(2.55233742331288, 
    2.10490416666667, 1.99411854951185, 1.87502664796634, 1.76141805555556, 
    1.68473435326843), X465 = c(2.54993251533742, 2.10804166666667, 
    1.99814644351464, 1.88111360448808, 1.76530277777778, 1.68772322670375
    ), X467.5 = c(2.54192944785276, 2.10937638888889, 1.99570990237099, 
    1.88144319775596, 1.76786666666667, 1.69657162726008), X470 = c(2.45424233128834, 
    2.02388472222222, 1.91476011157601, 1.80086255259467, 1.68827638888889, 
    1.61762865090403), X472.5 = c(2.38808588957055, 1.96169583333333, 
    1.85649232914923, 1.74286956521739, 1.63194444444444, 1.56048400556328
    ), X475 = c(2.40716871165644, 1.98333055555556, 1.8761589958159, 
    1.7647840112202, 1.65609861111111, 1.58707093184979), X477.5 = c(2.38796012269939, 
    1.96411527777778, 1.85740725244073, 1.74938990182328, 1.64029444444444, 
    1.57306258692629), X480 = c(2.32367484662577, 1.90594027777778, 
    1.80042677824268, 1.69331276297335, 1.58667777777778, 1.51872322670375
    ), X482.5 = c(2.26839877300614, 1.85602638888889, 1.75232914923291, 
    1.64626928471248, 1.542725, 1.47292350486787), X485 = c(2.24077914110429, 
    1.82308194444444, 1.72304323570432, 1.61980925666199, 1.5158, 
    1.44215159944367), X487.5 = c(2.19346625766871, 1.77742916666667, 
    1.67717712691771, 1.57596213183731, 1.46934861111111, 1.39640751043115
    ), X490 = c(2.1796226993865, 1.77528611111111, 1.67270432357043, 
    1.56773772791024, 1.46491111111111, 1.39967732962448), X492.5 = c(2.19796932515337, 
    1.79399861111111, 1.69254253835425, 1.58660028050491, 1.48578888888889, 
    1.42326842837274), X495 = c(2.16203067484663, 1.75784722222222, 
    1.66087866108787, 1.56017812061711, 1.45659583333333, 1.39502364394993
    ), X497.5 = c(2.12128220858896, 1.72433055555556, 1.62827615062762, 
    1.52875175315568, 1.42800833333333, 1.36483727399165), X500 = c(2.10455214723926, 
    1.71279027777778, 1.61463458856346, 1.51266058906031, 1.41571388888889, 
    1.35290403337969), X502.5 = c(2.09321779141104, 1.70464027777778, 
    1.60352022315202, 1.50263674614306, 1.40064722222222, 1.34636300417246
    ), X505 = c(2.06455828220859, 1.67302916666667, 1.57388145048815, 
    1.47552734922861, 1.37514166666667, 1.31759944367177), X507.5 = c(2.01607975460123, 
    1.62675138888889, 1.53272524407252, 1.43562692847125, 1.34284444444444, 
    1.27975660639777), X510 = c(1.97671165644172, 1.59260694444444, 
    1.50193444909344, 1.41013043478261, 1.31677916666667, 1.25430876216968
    ), X512.5 = c(1.96352147239264, 1.57798472222222, 1.48636262203626, 
    1.39764375876578, 1.30225555555556, 1.23669680111266), X515 = c(1.92503987730061, 
    1.54797083333333, 1.45469456066946, 1.36199298737728, 1.26766805555556, 
    1.21219749652295), X517.5 = c(1.90465030674847, 1.53300555555556, 
    1.44391352859135, 1.35238569424965, 1.2612375, 1.20831293463143
    ), X520 = c(1.87689570552147, 1.50217916666667, 1.4149330543933, 
    1.32729733520337, 1.23678194444445, 1.17577329624478), X522.5 = c(1.83759202453988, 
    1.46538888888889, 1.37917015341702, 1.29119775596073, 1.20174861111111, 
    1.14477607788595), X525 = c(1.83651533742331, 1.46525, 1.38037935843794, 
    1.29450490883591, 1.2079125, 1.15156189151599), X527.5 = c(1.82067791411043, 
    1.45758472222222, 1.36769874476987, 1.28326788218794, 1.19442916666667, 
    1.13923365785814), X530 = c(1.7854754601227, 1.42325833333333, 
    1.33740446304045, 1.25485553997195, 1.16439166666667, 1.11009457579972
    ), X532.5 = c(1.72706134969325, 1.36137083333333, 1.28353277545328, 
    1.20330014025245, 1.1164875, 1.05959248956885), X535 = c(1.73546012269939, 
    1.37703333333333, 1.2953570432357, 1.21220617110799, 1.12938333333333, 
    1.07361335187761), X537.5 = c(1.75189570552147, 1.39752083333333, 
    1.3135160390516, 1.23146283309958, 1.15030416666667, 1.10116133518776
    ), X540 = c(1.70230061349693, 1.35148888888889, 1.2665369595537, 
    1.18725666199158, 1.10636944444444, 1.06070792767733), X542.5 = c(1.71566564417178, 
    1.36359027777778, 1.28287029288703, 1.20369565217391, 1.1235375, 
    1.07357719054242), X545 = c(1.66589877300613, 1.31230416666667, 
    1.23633891213389, 1.15782889200561, 1.07775833333333, 1.01979972183588
    ), X547.5 = c(1.62098466257669, 1.27635555555556, 1.19730962343096, 
    1.11939270687237, 1.03757361111111, 0.990175243393602), X550 = c(1.64088650306749, 
    1.30173333333333, 1.22275592747559, 1.14718793828892, 1.06357916666667, 
    1.02470931849791), X552.5 = c(1.65776687116564, 1.31616944444444, 
    1.23976708507671, 1.16367180925666, 1.08286944444444, 1.03624200278164
    ), X555 = c(1.64775766871166, 1.30469861111111, 1.23003905160391, 
    1.15642496493689, 1.07983611111111, 1.02301529902643), X557.5 = c(1.57864417177914, 
    1.24234861111111, 1.16718131101813, 1.09518373071529, 1.01922638888889, 
    0.966821974965229), X560 = c(1.55608895705521, 1.22404166666667, 
    1.14994979079498, 1.07797896213184, 0.998729166666667, 0.953904033379694
    ), X562.5 = c(1.57327300613497, 1.24271111111111, 1.17039748953975, 
    1.10076437587658, 1.02429722222222, 0.982093184979138), X565 = c(1.54155828220859, 
    1.21247638888889, 1.14011994421199, 1.06987377279102, 0.995325, 
    0.950226703755216), X567.5 = c(1.5184754601227, 1.19163194444444, 
    1.11808926080893, 1.04673772791024, 0.969984722222222, 0.920390820584145
    ), X570 = c(1.52191104294479, 1.19953472222222, 1.12552022315202, 
    1.05369144460028, 0.979043055555555, 0.936059805285118), 
    X572.5 = c(1.49422699386503, 1.17113333333333, 1.09843793584379, 
    1.02884291725105, 0.956215277777778, 0.914119610570236), 
    X575 = c(1.48120552147239, 1.16091666666667, 1.08878382147838, 
    1.02371248246844, 0.950745833333333, 0.903524339360223), 
    X577.5 = c(1.49473312883436, 1.17405, 1.10468340306834, 1.04081346423562, 
    0.967102777777778, 0.918347705146036), X580 = c(1.45893558282209, 
    1.13822638888889, 1.07150488145049, 1.004904628331, 0.931488888888889, 
    0.888706536856745), X582.5 = c(1.40335889570552, 1.08981666666667, 
    1.02136262203626, 0.955345021037868, 0.882438888888889, 0.842457579972184
    ), X585 = c(1.41981901840491, 1.11120277777778, 1.04046164574617, 
    0.976112201963534, 0.902045833333333, 0.854774687065369), 
    X587.5 = c(1.44122085889571, 1.13389722222222, 1.06531938633194, 
    0.998193548387097, 0.927052777777778, 0.884666203059805), 
    X590 = c(1.43262883435583, 1.12188472222222, 1.05589539748954, 
    0.991642356241234, 0.923915277777778, 0.883214186369958), 
    X592.5 = c(1.39457668711656, 1.08495694444444, 1.01676150627615, 
    0.954368863955119, 0.886066666666667, 0.842401947148818), 
    X595 = c(1.39473006134969, 1.09030138888889, 1.02193584379358, 
    0.95813744740533, 0.889866666666667, 0.851438108484006), 
    X597.5 = c(1.39176380368098, 1.08874305555556, 1.02160251046025, 
    0.960784011220196, 0.891755555555556, 0.851367176634214), 
    X600 = c(1.32321472392638, 1.02342361111111, 0.958054393305439, 
    0.896713884992987, 0.828456944444444, 0.789112656467316), 
    X602.5 = c(1.3699754601227, 1.06539861111111, 1.00389818688982, 
    0.94194950911641, 0.875038888888889, 0.832920723226704), 
    X605 = c(1.39004294478528, 1.0856125, 1.02410460251046, 0.964893408134642, 
    0.897881944444444, 0.851397774687065), X607.5 = c(1.33887423312883, 
    1.04344305555556, 0.978672245467225, 0.918176718092567, 0.853443055555556, 
    0.810876216968011), X610 = c(1.34292944785276, 1.04911111111111, 
    0.98465690376569, 0.922030855539972, 0.858780555555556, 0.820618915159944
    ), X612.5 = c(1.32123006134969, 1.02857083333333, 0.962319386331939, 
    0.899249649368864, 0.834901388888889, 0.797037552155772), 
    X615 = c(1.30576380368098, 1.01544166666667, 0.949560669456067, 
    0.889232819074334, 0.824005555555556, 0.787675938803894), 
    X617.5 = c(1.30801840490798, 1.01950138888889, 0.959458856345886, 
    0.902255259467041, 0.839116666666667, 0.80459388038943), 
    X620 = c(1.25273619631902, 0.963565277777778, 0.903634588563459, 
    0.845955119214586, 0.781859722222222, 0.751739916550765), 
    X622.5 = c(1.24233742331288, 0.951993055555556, 0.889652719665272, 
    0.832720897615708, 0.765165277777778, 0.728485396383866), 
    X625 = c(1.3115736196319, 1.020975, 0.960577405857741, 0.902300140252454, 
    0.835329166666667, 0.789098748261474), X627.5 = c(1.32251840490798, 
    1.03869861111111, 0.977846582984658, 0.916507713884993, 0.852429166666667, 
    0.812655076495132), X630 = c(1.26833435582822, 0.9928125, 
    0.93086750348675, 0.87539270687237, 0.812751388888889, 0.775739916550765
    ), X632.5 = c(1.24898773006135, 0.965934722222222, 0.908059972105997, 
    0.85682889200561, 0.794722222222222, 0.751435326842837), 
    X635 = c(1.28299386503067, 0.995876388888889, 0.936375174337517, 
    0.881263674614306, 0.819331944444444, 0.78326842837274), 
    X637.5 = c(1.2784018404908, 1.00060833333333, 0.939645746164575, 
    0.880981767180926, 0.821463888888889, 0.792333796940195), 
    X640 = c(1.24037116564417, 0.960616666666667, 0.905357043235704, 
    0.846816269284712, 0.787144444444444, 0.744055632823366), 
    X642.5 = c(1.19373619631902, 0.907856944444444, 0.852075313807531, 
    0.797594670406732, 0.732779166666667, 0.684244784422809), 
    X645 = c(1.17663190184049, 0.898422222222222, 0.835518828451883, 
    0.782708274894811, 0.717233333333333, 0.684310152990264), 
    X647.5 = c(1.21073619631902, 0.943138888888889, 0.879875871687587, 
    0.826015427769986, 0.7630125, 0.737840055632823), X650 = c(1.20088036809816, 
    0.934829166666667, 0.877008368200837, 0.821608695652174, 
    0.760254166666667, 0.727004172461752), X652.5 = c(1.18600920245399, 
    0.915881944444444, 0.860887029288703, 0.80358064516129, 0.744027777777778, 
    0.705867872044506), X655 = c(1.22061349693252, 0.951930555555556, 
    0.896224546722455, 0.840730715287518, 0.784806944444444, 
    0.750878998609179), X657.5 = c(1.19243865030675, 0.924801388888889, 
    0.865479776847978, 0.81258064516129, 0.757759722222222, 0.721283727399165
    ), X660 = c(1.10550920245399, 0.841702777777778, 0.780730822873082, 
    0.731366058906031, 0.673393055555556, 0.638547983310153)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

My code:

```
Data <- data.frame(Data)
library(rgl)
library(pls)
x <- as.POSIXct(Data$Date, format = "2013-01-10", tz = "Australia/Adelaide")
y <- Data$Wavelength
z <- as.matrix(Data[,3:167])
open3d()
plot3d(x, y, z,col="purple", size=3, xlab = "Date", ylab = "Wavelength", zlab = "Absorbance (/cm)")
```

I get a not very nice plot as shown in the second graph.

[image]

The x-axis has labels in numerical dates,  but I want the actual dates in the format like "1 June 2013" or "1/6/2013". 
I also don't know how to make a nice rainbow colour looking 3D graph.

Any help is welcome :)

a typical UV-Vis spectrum looks like graph 3 below [image: example UV-Vis spectrum]

using the codes provided by Marco Sandri,

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
Data %>%
  gather(Series, y, X250:X660, factor_key=TRUE) %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~Date, y = ~Wavelength, z = ~y, 
          type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'lines', color = ~Series)
```

The graph 4 is the plot I get.

[image: good 3D-plot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution based on the `plotly` package:

```
library(tidyr)
library(plotly)

Data %>%
  gather(Series, y, X250:X660, factor_key=TRUE) %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~Date, y = ~Wavelength, z = ~y, type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'lines', color = ~Series)
```

[image]

Comment: @ Marco Sandri, thanks so much for answering my question about the 3D plot. Your codes look wonderful! Unfortunately, I don't understand the code well. Why do you use "series" in the code? The absorbance at wavelength 250nm should be much higher than the absorbance at 600nm on the graph, but the 3D-plot showed the opposite using your code, could you help to correct it?

Comment: @Linda Hi Linda.  I used `gather`  to transform `Data` from a "wide" to a "long" format. `Series` is a categorical variable created by `gather` with 165 categories (the names of the 165 series: `X250`, `X252.5`, ...). With `color = ~Series`, `plot_ly` plots and colors each series using a different color.

Comment: @Linda About your question _absorbance at wavelength 250nm should be much higher than the absorbance at 600nm_, `wavelength` ranges in `Data` from 250 to 262.5. I cannot see 600nm. Where do you find this value? Maybe the `X600` column is connected to this wavelength?

Comment: @ Marco Sandri, many thanks for your explanation. I have edited my question, you can see on a typical UV-Vis spectrum, the absorbance on the 250nm side (left) is much higher than the absorbance on the 600nm side (right). I have used your codes to plot a 3D graph, you can see on the 3D plot, the absorbance of 250nm is much lower than the absorbance of 600nm. Thanks very much for your kindness and patient. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may omit and redraw the axes using `bbox3d`. In `bbox3d` just `xat=` and `xlab=` specifications are needed, where we use `x`.

```
open3d()
plot3d(x, y, z, col="purple", size=3, xlab="Date", ylab="Wavelength", 
       zlab="Absorbance (/cm)", axes=FALSE, top=TRUE)
bbox3d(xat=x, xlab=x, col="black", front="line", back="line", lit=FALSE)
```

[image]